# Rails 4: Creating Google Calendar event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-ruby-client

I'm trying to insert Google Calendar events as illustrated [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert). If I send the request with values hardcoded like the example it works fine:

```
event = {'summary' => 'Summary',
         'location' => 'Location',
         'start' => { 'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:00:00.000-07:00' },
         'end' => { 'dateTime' => '2011-06-03T10:25:00.000-07:00' }}
```

But it fails silently if I try to send variables:

```
event = {'summary' => "#{params[:summary]}",
         'location' => "#{params[:location]}",
         'start' => { 'dateTime' => "#{params[:start_time]}" },
         'end' => { 'dateTime' => "#{params[:start_time]}" }}
```

It also fails if I format this way:

```
event = "{
          \"summary\": \"#{params[:summary]}\",
          \"location\": \"#{params[:location]}\",
          \"start\": { \"dateTime\": \"#{params[:start_time]}\" },
          \"end\": { \"dateTime\": \"#{params[:end_time]}\" }
        }"
```

I can get it to successfully post with the `start_time` and `end_time` formatted like this: `Date.today.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%l:%M:%S.000-07:00")`, but that's less-than-ideal because I believe the `start_time` and `end_time` params are already `Time` objects.

The form is passing the parameters because I get this in the Rails console (`authenticity_token` omitted for brevity):

```
Started POST "/events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-15 08:53:36 -0600
Processing by EventsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
               "authenticity_token"=>"...",
               "event"=>{"summary"=>"Summary",
                         "start_time(1i)"=>"2015",
                         "start_time(2i)"=>"4",
                         "start_time(3i)"=>"15",
                         "start_time(4i)"=>"14",
                         "start_time(5i)"=>"54",
                         "end_time(1i)"=>"2015",
                         "end_time(2i)"=>"4",
                         "end_time(3i)"=>"15",
                         "end_time(4i)"=>"14",
                         "end_time(5i)"=>"55",
                         "location"=>"Location"},
               "commit"=>"Create Event"}
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new({:application_name => "PlannerApp",
                                :application_version => "1.0"})
client.authorization.access_token = t.fresh_token
service = client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
client.execute(:api_method => service.events.insert,
               :parameters => {'calendarId' => 'primary'},
               :body => JSON.dump(event),
               :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```

And here is what I get from Google (`Authorization` omitted for brevity):

```
Google::APIClient::Request Sending API request get https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/calendar/v3/rest {
  "User-Agent"=>"PlannerApp/1.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.5 Mac OS X/10.10.2\n (gzip)",
  "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip",
  "Content-Type"=>""}
Google::APIClient::Request Result: 200 {
  "expires"=>"Wed, 15 Apr 2015 14:58:37 GMT",
  "date"=>"Wed, 15 Apr 2015 14:53:37 GMT",
  "etag"=>"\"ye6orv2F-1npMW3u9suM3a7C5Bo/snCOExYvhrzEZTGzdubZtafuHVU\"",
  "vary"=>"Origin, X-Origin",
  "content-type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8",
  "x-content-type-options"=>"nosniff",
  "x-frame-options"=>"SAMEORIGIN",
  "x-xss-protection"=>"1; mode=block",
  "content-length"=>"93847",
  "server"=>"GSE",
  "cache-control"=>"public, max-age=300, must-revalidate, no-transform",
  "age"=>"0",
  "alternate-protocol"=>"443:quic,p=0.5",
  "connection"=>"close"}
Google::APIClient::Request Sending API request post https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events {
  "User-Agent"=>"PlannerApp/1.0 google-api-ruby-client/0.8.5 Mac OS X/10.10.2\n (gzip)",
  "Content-Type"=>"application/json",
  "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip",
  "Authorization"=>"Bearer ...",
  "Cache-Control"=>"no-store"}
```

How should I be formatting these `event` hash values to get a successful `POST`?

**SOLUTION:**

```
event = {'summary' => "#{params[:event][:summary]}",
         'location' => "#{params[:event][:location]}",
         'start' => { 'dateTime' => Time.new(params['event']['start_time(1i)'],
                                             params['event']['start_time(2i)'],
                                             params['event']['start_time(3i)'],
                                             params['event']['start_time(4i)'],
                                             params['event']['start_time(5i)'])
                                        .to_datetime.rfc3339,
                      'timeZone' => "America/Denver" },
         'end' => { 'dateTime' => Time.new(params['event']['end_time(1i)'],
                                           params['event']['end_time(2i)'],
                                           params['event']['end_time(3i)'],
                                           params['event']['end_time(4i)'],
                                           params['event']['end_time(5i)'])
                                      .to_datetime.rfc3339,
                    'timeZone' => "America/Denver" }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params are nested. So it would be:

```
event = {'summary' => "#{params[:event][:summary]}",
     'location' => "#{params[:event][:location]}",
     'start' => { 'dateTime' => "#{params[:event][:start_time]}" },
     'end' => { 'dateTime' => "#{params[:event][:start_time]}" }}
```

Comment: Good catch - thanks!  This solved the part of my question about the strings (`summary` and `location`), but not for the times (`start_time` and `end_time`). Do you have any idea on those?  They are _time_ fields both in the database and on the form.  `"#{params[:event][:start_time]}"` doesn't work, but according to the reference [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), `dateTime` should receive a `datetime` value. I've also tried adding `'timeZone' => "America/Denver"` to the `start` and `end` hashes, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Based on the params you are getting back, you would have to build them up.

Grrr...sorry SO submitted too early. 

See how your are getting your date in pieces? i.e.

    ```"start_time(1i)"=>"2015",
                         "start_time(2i)"=>"4", # your month
                         "start_time(3i)"=>"15",
                         "start_time(4i)"=>"14", # your day
                         "start_time(5i)"=>"54",
                         "end_time(1i)"=>"2015" # your year```

Comment: So to get the year piece (the year), you would use ```"#{params[:event][:start_time(1i)]}"```

Comment: Also, whenever you get it working, can you mark this answer and the correct resolution?  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks again for such a quick response! I am passing this: `"#{params[:event][:start_time[1]]}-#{params[:event][:start_time[2]]}-#{params[:event][:start_time[3]]}T#{params[:event][:start_time[4]]}:#{params[:event][:start_time[5]]}"` to `dateTime` and passing `"America/Denver"` to `'timeZone'`, but it's not working. Is that what you had in mind? I'm sure I'm missing something very simple in the formatting.

Comment: I would do ```Time.new("#{params[:event][:start_time(1i)]}", "#{params[:event][:start_time(2i)]}", "#{params[:event][:start_time(3i)]}")``` or something similar depending on where the day, month, and year are actually coming from. You can continue that pattern to add hours and mins as well.

Comment: So the entire line would be something like:

```'start' => { 'dateTime' => Time.new("#{params[:event][:start_time(1i)]}", "#{params[:event][:start_time(2i)]}", "#{params[:event][:start_time(3i)]}")}```

Again, you may need to add hour/min/sec too, but just follow that pattern.

Comment: Ok, just got home and tried your suggestion... and a couple variations: `Time.new("#{params[:event][:start_time(1i)]}")` gives `syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ']'`; `Time.new("#{params[:event][:start_time[(1i)]]}")` gives `can't convert 0+1i into Integer`; `Time.new("#{params[:event][:start_time[1]]}")` gives `argument out of range`. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: OK. Sorry. I was overcomplicating it by tryting to force string interpolation where it didn't need to be. This has been tested and will work just fine: ```Time.new(params['event']['start_time(1i)'], params['event']['start_time(2i)'], params['event']['start_time(3i)'])```

Comment: Thanks, but no luck. I parsed the JSON result and here's the error when I use your format: `{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-16 00:00:00 -0600\" is malformed at \" 00:00:00 -0600\""}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-16 00:00:00 -0600\" is malformed at \" 00:00:00 -0600\""}}`

Comment: If I include seconds it looks like: `{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"invalid", "message"=>"Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-16 16:06:00 -0600\" is malformed at \" 16:06:00 -0600\""}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Invalid value for: Invalid format: \"2015-04-16 16:06:00 -0600\" is malformed at \" 16:06:00 -0600\""}}`

Comment: Ah. yes. bc we have to pass it to Google in a specific datetime format of rfc3339. So append ```.to_datetime.rfc3339``` to the end. for a total line of:  ```Time.new(params['event']['start_time(1i)'], params['event']['start_time(2i)'], params['event']['start_time(3i)'], params['event']['start_time(4i)'], params['event']['start_time(4i)']).to_datetime.rfc3339```

Comment: Brilliant! That's the ticket. Thanks so much. I'll accept this and update my question with your solution.